# Props and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple list and I want to show or hide certain text if string is longer than 0 but I always get the same output("C") and it doesn't change even after the update

```
    <li>{props.sen}{props.sen.length > 0 ? "" : "C"}</li>
    <li>{props.sax}{props.sax.length > 0 ? "" : "C"}</li>
    <li>{props.sac}{props.sac.length > 0 ? "" : "C"}</li>
```

Initial state for `sen`,`sax` and `sac` is `""` but even after update where state updates to "value", `C` still remains.

Comment: You're updating your data incorrectly. You're reading from props but you mention updating `state`. Please post more relevant code.

Comment: We need all your code to help you.

Comment: Sorry for not answering... the solution is { (props.sac.length == 0 ? "" : "C") } when I added the brackets it started working

Comment: hey, @OunknownO, feel free to mark this question as answered :)

Comment: You posted `==` instead of `>` in your comment. It sounds like that was your solution, not adding parenthesis. If that's the case I would probably close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the brackets, try this:

```
 <li>{props.sen}{(props.sen.length > 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
 <li>{props.sax}{(props.sax.length > 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
 <li>{props.sac}{(props.sac.length > 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
```

Comment: Adding parenthesis* is not related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was removing ">" and adding "==" instead of it. This is the correct code

```
 <li>{props.sen}{(props.sen.length == 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
 <li>{props.sax}{(props.sax.length == 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
 <li>{props.sac}{(props.sac.length == 0 ? "" : "C")}</li>
```